# After DNN Database migration, DNN shows a successful log in in the EventLog table, but It actually does not have me logged in

Tags: database, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

So I have moved a good number of DNN database/websites and not encountered the following issue.

After moving and getting the site back up and running, when I try to log into the site with either a Super User or typical user account the following happens:

- if I type in the wrong password I get an expected wrong password error
- if I put in the correct password the EventLog table shows a successful login, but I am not logged in and it redirects me to the login page.

I have checked that in deed it does not see that I am logged in by going to areas that I can't without it requesting me to login.

I moved the DNN database the same way I have a number of times: backed up database and restored it on the new SQL host server.  Updated the portalAlias table entries.  The site is obviously up as I can get to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: most probably, this is looking like a hosting issue, I encountered same error before when my website was pointing to the parent folder of the dnn website root. Everything was working without errors but was not able to login, some times login button disappears etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try clearing your browser cache. I have at times had the browser cache freeze the cookie and apparently keep me from logging in or at times from logging out.

I those cases I clear the cache and all temporary files. Then if that still doesnt fix it i break out the virtual machine and try it from a broser on another machine.